# BackgroundImage Javafx Combobox

Tags: button, javafx, combobox, background

is there a way to set an Image (like setGraphic() for Button) for a ComboBox?

```
file = new File(IMG_DIR + "load.png");
BackgroundImage bg = new BackgroundImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()),BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
            BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
comboBox.setBackground(new Background(bg));
```

That's what i tried, but it only results in a black background.
As comparison, what i do with my buttons:

```
File file = new File(IMG_DIR + "save.png");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
buttonSave.setGraphic(imageView);
```

what it currently looks like:

[image: what it currently looks like]

I want a load image on the ComboBox positioned like the images on the Buttons. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you want graphics on the items ... not the combo box.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, but maybe combining question&answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030534/javafx-combobox-image works.

Comment: @fabian i found that already, but i thought there might be an easier way...